# Is there a way to sort a list in python until the first sorted k elements are found?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I have a normal boring list of non sorted numbers. From that list I need to take the first k elements after sorting. The thing is that if the list is considerably long and k is considerably small sorting the entire list seems like a waste. I came up with an algorithmic solution for this, but requires me to write my own implementation for sorting, my question is: is there a way to get the same efficiency using something already implemented in python?

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify, I know this will give the answer I need: `sorted(boring_list)[:n]`

But my concern is efficiency: **I don't need to sort the whole list for this.**

Comment: The very first recipe seems to fit the bill here.  See [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) page.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the numbers in the list? Or are they random numbers (of any size) in a random order?

Comment: @squiguy: I think the OP is looking for the *smallest* n elements, not simply the first.  (Since it's a list, `boring_list[:n]` would suffice if that were true.)

Comment: @Sofia: Is it a solution involving k iterations or anything better ? You could do a bubble sort with k iterations to get that . Usually merge sort is n log n efficiency so if kn < n log n scenarios it should be better . But hope you store the sorted items in a list so that in next iteration its not repeated ?

Comment: @squiguy I don't think that takes sorting into account.

Comment: @Rob It is a list with distances from one fixed geographic point and other geographic points, the other geographic points are random so, yes, I guess the list is just random integers in random order.

Comment: @Nishant actually quicksort may be more efficient with certain considerations for this, but my question is if it can be done using just python libs (without writing the code myself).

Comment: @DSM I know.  You can just use `sorted` first.  Should have mentioned that.

Comment: @SofiaBravo Just use `sorted` first.

Comment: @DSM yes, exactly I need the first n smallest elements.

Comment: @squiguy Precisely what I want to avoid is sorting the whole list when I only need the smallest n elements.

Comment: @F.J did you remove your answer? If so, why?

Comment: @SofiaBravo Sorry should have commented here when I deleted it.  I posted my answer with timing information based on a faulty assumption.  I thought that with `heapq.nsmallest` you first had to convert your list to a heap (and you don't), so my timing results were incorrectly comparing sorting to that heap conversion operation.

Comment: You *can* solve this problem in expected `O(n + k log k)` time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module, in particular its [`nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) or [`nsmallest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) functions.

Alternatively just build the heap and call [`heappop()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop). This should take O(n) time to build the heap and O(k*log(n)) to retrieve the `k` elements.

---

Here's a very simple and small benchmark:

```
In [1]: import random, heapq

In [2]: seq = [random.randint(-5000, 5000) for _ in range(35000)]

In [3]: %timeit sorted(seq)[:75]
100 loops, best of 3: 14.5 ms per loop

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: s = seq[:]
   ...: heapq.nsmallest(75, s)
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.05 ms per loop

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: s = seq[:]
   ...: heapq.heapify(s)
   ...: for _ in range(75): heapq.heappop(s)
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.41 ms per loop
```

I have no idea why `nsmallest` is so much slower then calling `heappop` directly. In fact I should have timed it without copying `seq` but still:

```
In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: heapq.nsmallest(75, seq)
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.82 ms per loop
```

Increasing the length by 100 times:

```
In [12]: %timeit sorted(seq)[:75]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.9 s per loop

In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: heapq.nsmallest(75, seq)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 352 ms per loop

In [14]: %%timeit
    ...: s = seq[:]
    ...: heapq.heapify(s)
    ...: for _ in range(75): heapq.heappop(s)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 264 ms per loop
```

---

Note: to counter F.J biased profiling:

```
In [13]: a = list(range(1000000))

In [14]: random.shuffle(a)

In [15]: %timeit sorted(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 985 ms per loop

In [16]: %%timeit
    ...: s = a[:]
    ...: heapq.heapify(s)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 284 ms per loop
```

As you can see `heapify` is quite faster then sorting even on 1000000 elements lists.

Comment: You didn't store the results of `heapq.heappop(s)` anywhere. How does storing that in a list affect the timing?

Comment: @RobWatts No significant change. From 2.41ms to 2.42 and from 264 ms to 265ms.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`heapq.nsmallest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest).

Maintaining the heap invariant is O(logk) where *k* is the size of the heap; you have to perform *n* push operations, making the overall complexity O(n logk).  Compare this to sorting-and-taking-the-first-k-elements, which is overall complexity O(n logn).  When k is small compared to n, the heapq approach clearly wins.

When k approaches n, you should instead just sort and take the first k - timsort is really good :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would write my own function for it.

```
import sys
def sort_first_k(iterable,k):
    lst = [sys.maxsize]
    max_ = (sys.maxsize,0) # (sys.maxint,0) on python2

    for el in iterable:
        if el < max_[0]:
            lst.append(el)
            if len(lst) > k: lst.pop(max_[1])
                tmp = max(lst)
                max_ = (tmp, lst.index(tmp))
    return sorted(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a selection algorithm like [median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) then you can get the first k elements in `O(n)`. Then sorting these k elements take only `O(k log k)`. So, this all takes `O(n + k log k)`

Comment: That's exactly what I have in mind but again, my question is if can be done with something already written in python.

Comment: O(n + klog(k)) = O(n). Also it's known that the median of medians algorithm has quite big constant factors, and that's why almost any implementation of quicksort simply use a random selection instead of relying on it.

Comment: That's interesting about quicksort. But how could O(n + klog(k)) = O(n)?  For ex. if k = n, then it's O(n + n log n)

Answer (score 0):

why would you sort it ??? thats not what the assignment asks for

```
def nsmallest(some_list,N):
    tmp = some_list[:]
    xiter = (x for x in iter(lambda:min(tmp),'') if not tmp.remove(x))
    return [val for i,val in zip(range(N),xiter)]
```

this should be O(k*n)

```
In [52]: the_list = [random.randint(-100,1000) for _ in range(1000000)]

In [53]: %timeit nsmallest(the_list,3)
10 loops, best of 3: 66.9 ms per loop
```